# RDBMS Splitting a column into many columns with respect to a field

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I am creating a web application based on attendance system. I am using MySQL and PHP. I have a table for every employee that has took attendance and they keep adding when the employees takes attendance on the machine. I extracted the employees that has has attendance 2 times per day which are in and out, and I added them to a table with columns. Now I want to extract the attendances for the employees that has took attendance 1 per day or more than 2 per day which they are error and i want to add them to a table employee `time1`, `time2` and `time3`.

I have a table as this design, it's an attendance system,
I need to split the time if the attendance count per day was not equal to 2, which are error logs.

```
id    pd     time        date
1     5      07:05       08/07/2014
2     4      18:02       07/07/2014
3     1      07:05       06/07/2014
4     1      07:06       06/07/2014
5     1      18:00       06/07/2014
```

I need to add them to a table in the database and to be split in that form with respect the `pd` and `date`.

```
id   pd     time1     time2       time3    ....     date
1    5      07:05                                   08/07/2014
2    4      18:02                                   07/07/2014
3    1      07:05     07:06       18:00             06/07/2014
```

sorry guys its my first post in my whole entire life , so forgive me if am doing something wrong or not complete

Comment: Please take a __[tour]__. And __format__ your question. It's hard to read.

Comment: And while you're at, take a look at the [home page](http://stackoverflow.com/) and check how many questions, even bad ones, have a title similar to yours.

Comment: The term for "over(partition by ..)` is "window function" and MySQL does not support them, so your title does not make sense.

Comment: You provided 3 items that I applaud you for: `sample data`, `expected result` and `dbms type`. Thank you. It will be easier next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following result, which isn't an exact match to your request, but it may get you started. It doesn't attempt to list all the starting times, but does count the number of entries per `pd` per `date` so any that are not equal to 2 can be detected easily.

```
| ID | PD | MIN_TIME | COUNT_TIME | MAX_TIME |                          DATE |
|----|----|----------|------------|----------|-------------------------------|
|  3 |  1 |    07:05 |          3 |    18:00 |   June, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 |  4 |    18:02 |          1 |    18:02 |   July, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|  1 |  5 |    07:05 |          1 |    07:05 | August, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

The query for this is:

```
SELECT
      MIN(id)     AS id
    , pd
    , MIN(time)   AS min_time
    , COUNT(time) AS count_time
    , MAX(time)   AS max_time
    , date
FROM AttendanceTbl
GROUP BY
      pd
    , date
ORDER BY
      pd
    , date
```

You can review it at [this SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d17819/3)

---

Suggestions.

- include table name(s) as well as the sample data.
- consider using http://sqlfiddle.com to provide a working example for development of the solution

Note:
 - I really don't like using `date` or `time` as field names, I know MySQL lets you do it but I can't recommend it.

Comment: Its a great answer , but it would be perfect if i can show the times that he took the attendance instead of counting them

Comment: Bad luck I'm afraid, this is as far as I'm prepared to go. Sorry. What you are asking for is quite complex and to be absolutely frank I think will disappoint anyway. You are free to ignore my advice, but this simple `group by` will perform quite well and be useful in managing that data. Best of luck.

Comment: its ok than am not lukcy :D

Comment: hey, I have actually done you a favour, believe me. I have given you 90% of what you wanted for 10% of the effort. (almost none at your end), the "last little bit" you want will cost you dearly in effort! It requires "dynamic sql" and its a nightmare you just will not get great benefit from.

Comment: Just imagine this. A workstation get's the enter key stuck (or pushed down by a pile of books) all of a sudden hundreds of rows appear in the table for the same event (the form is being submitted over and over) - do you want hundreds of columns? it would probably break anyway. But counting it, no problem. My friend you have a bargain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution thank alot for all :)

$sql="SELECT MIN(id) AS id,date, enrollnumber,

```
       MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=1 THEN time END)) AS time1,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=2 THEN time END)) AS time2,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=3 THEN time END)) AS time3,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=4 THEN time END)) AS time4,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=5 THEN time END)) AS time5,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=6 THEN time END)) AS time6,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=7 THEN time END)) AS time7,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=8 THEN time END)) AS time8,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=9 THEN time END)) AS time9,
           MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=10 THEN time END)) AS time10
    FROM (
          SELECT t.id, t.enrollnumber, t.time, t.date,
                 (SELECT 1+COUNT(*)
                  FROM attlog AS sub
                  WHERE sub.enrollnumber=t.enrollnumber AND
                        sub.date=t.date AND (
                        sub.time<t.time OR
                        sub.time=t.time AND sub.id<t.id)) AS ordinal
          FROM attlog AS t
         ) AS x
    GROUP BY enrollnumber, date";
```